# How to get a sum elements of a keyup in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, sum

I have "N" inputs in a formgroup that i need to get the sum:

```
<input (keyup)="sum($event)" type="text" name="estoque_variacao{{i}}" class="form-control" id="estoque_variacao{{i}}" formControlName="estoque_variacao">
```

My Typescript:

```
sum(value){
    let sum;
    if(sum == null){
      sum = 0;
    }
    sum =  +Number(value.key);
}
```

When i press "22", i get just:

> 2.

I already try:

```
sum += parseFloat(valor.key);
```

But i get the same response

How can i do this?

I need something like this, but in angular/typescript:

http://jsfiddle.net/35At5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current Implementation can handle only one control only however you need to sum up from all dynamic generated controls.

> Follow the steps

### 1. In ts file

Create a object which can holds all the control model.

```
public controls = {};
```

### 2. in html

```
<input [(ngModel)]="controls[i]" (keyup)="sum($event)" type="text" name="estoque_variacao{{i}}" class="form-control" id="estoque_variacao{{i}}" formControlName="estoque_variacao">
```

ngModel will create the property inside the `controls` object

### 3. Final

Finally need to get the values of `controls` object and sum it up.

```
 let sum = 0;
 Object.keys(this.controls).map(key => {
   sum +=  +this.controls[key];
 });
 console.log(sum);
```

That's all  !

Comment: In a first input i put: 13, in a second i put 13, my response is 01313

Comment: if i declare the sum in a global (sum: number = 0;)   sum(){
    Object.keys(this.controls).map(key => {
      this.sum += this.controls[key];
    });
    console.log(this.sum);
  }

 i receive: 01131311313

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Your keyup event only preserves what you entered at keyup, it has no knowledge of previous key up events. You can however get the inputs of each of your form controls by calling the `formControl.value()` method and summing up your form controls.

Comment: how can i get a instant formcontrol.value change without using keyup?

Comment: Your can always subscribe to changes to the value of the form control.

Comment: how can i do this?

Comment: @RenaotPLS here's a good article on the subject: https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-valuechanges/